# Declaring an array of objects in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object, nsarray

I was studying the below objective c sample code. My question is that, when creating a method taking an array as parameter `-(int) match: (NSArray *)otherCards;` Does it imply that the objects in that array are cards, because it is declared in `Card.h`? I don't understand where does the `card` in `if ([card.contents isEqualToString:self.contents])` come from. Many thanks for your help!

```
￼ Card.h
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  @interface Card : NSObject
  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *contents;
  @property (nonatomic, getter=isChosen) BOOL chosen;
  @property (nonatomic, getter=isMatched) BOOL matched;
  - (int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards;
  @end

Card.m
interface Card()
@end
@implementation Card
- (int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards
{
     int score = 0;
     if ([card.contents isEqualToString:self.contents]) {
        score = 1;
}
  return score;
}
@end
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`card` is undefined in this code. It will not compile unless it's a global constant or something. Also, `otherCards` is unused within `match:`.

I suspect this code is supposed to be in a loop, maybe like this:

```
- (int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards
{
    int score = 0;

    for (Card *card in otherCards) {
        if ([card.contents isEqualToString:self.contents]) {
            score++;
        }
    }

    return score;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron! So after adding the for loop like you did, the code should be able to compile? I mean with`Card *card`, it defines a method that takes an NSArray of Card object as parameter?

Comment: I have been using Java. I'm not sure if it's ok to use a variable, say an array `otherCards` in this case, without specifying what's in the array..

Comment: Objective-C arrays are not typed. My sample code presupposes that the array is filled with `Card` objects, but if other objects are in there, `card.contents` will cause a crash (unless the other object has a `contents` property too.) You can use `respondsToSelector:` or `isKindOfClass:` to verify method implementation or class membership at runtime. (Notably, Swift arrays are typed, unlike Obj-C arrays.)

Answer (score 1):

No, the compiler don't check the content of NSArray. You can put any kind of object inside, so you should always check that the objects are of the type you want.

And, like Aaron said that code will not compile...